# Can't specific file name with FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

FileSaver.js https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Tested in Chrome and Safari. Chrome save file as `download` and Safari save file as `unknown`.

Tried

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

and

```
var file = new File(["Hello, world!"], "hello world.txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(file);
```

both not work.

Comment: is `FileSaver` from an npm package?  which one?  There is a filesaver module but it doesn't have a `saveAs` function (https://www.npmjs.com/package/filesaver)

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
i download from this github, and use `<script ...>` tag to use it in my webpage